# Android Tabs and Different ActionBar Menu Items

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I have a TabGroup in my app. How  can I have different actions items for each Tab ? I just found an example from [here](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/07/android-tabs-and-actionbar-menu-items/), but it is not enough for me.

Can someone provide some hints or at least a link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using SlidingTabLayout, and this is the way i changed the Toolbar icons for each Tab.

I've 3 tabs, each tab got its own fragment, and in each fragment I've created the following:

Tab 1 fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.tab_1_menu, menu);
}
```

Tab 2 fragment:

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.tab_2_menu, menu);
}
```

And so on, hope this help .

Full Example with getItemId / Click

```
             @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Set The Menu View
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //Menu Items, every fragment menu item
    //Must have different ID 
    if (id == R.id.settings) {
         //Do Something here
        );
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.About) {
         //Do Something here
        );
        return true;
    }
    if ( id == R.id.exit)
    {
        finish();
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Does the create method same with activity /

Comment: this onCreateOptions, it's different from the onCreate in the activity .

Comment: Can you provide more code ? I want to know how can the icons work (onOptionsItemSelected)

Comment: onOptionsItemSelected ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it .

BTW, here is a tutorial about SlidingTabLayout : http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html